# asp .net core wcf endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, configuration, wsdl

I am working on a small web API that calls a WSDL soap api. The WSDL file has an endpoint set, but I would like to be able to change that in the appsetting.json file so I can have different endpoints for different environments (DEV, Production, etc.)  I know in traditional .NET you could set the endpoints in the web.config file, so I tried to emulate that in the appsettings.json

```
 "client": {
   "endpoint": {
   "address": "https://testaddress.com:9000",
   "binding": "basicHttpBinding",
   "bindingConfiguration": "MyWSDLService_Binder",
   "contract": "MyWSDLNamespace.Service__PortType",
   "name": "MyWSDLService_Port"
 }
}
```

I set the `bindingConfiguration` to the `name` attribute in the node `<wsdl:binding>` in the actual WSDL and the `contract` to the `type` of that same node with the namespace of the WCF dot notated in front. The `name:` I set to the `name`  attribute of the `<wsdl:port>` node. Essentially I want to be able to set `<soap:address location>` in the appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 2):

Base on this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2259#issuecomment-326344828), in ASP.NET Core, it is no yet possible to do configuration in separate configuration files. It's set just from code.

Unfortunately you have to stick with code for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm three and a half years late with an answer here.  But, since no one answered it I thought I'd give it a crack.

in Startup.cs ConfigureServices handler add:

```
services.AddScoped<IServiceWeb, ServiceWebClient>(
(c) => 
  new ServiceWebClient(
     ServiceWebClient.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IServiceWeb, 
     Configuration["client:endpoint:address"]
  )
);
```